# streamlit run myfile.py - error if I try to run this in the Terminal opened in new Environment in Anaconda after installing streamlit

Tags: python, installation, streamlit

First of all, I am new in programming. I think it is very interesting, frustrating and exciting. All in one. I want to use streamlit to make the front end of an app, but when I follow the instructions to install it using Anaconda, all seems fine. But then the site tells me to write "streamlit run myfile.py", and then I have a massive quantity of errors. The first one is that myfile.py does not exist, but I understand that I need it to start using streamlit.

I want to focus in Python, which is why I want to use streamlit, to start. All help is really welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a file myfile.py?

Comment: You can try by posting those errors here. Use ```   ``` to post your code. Otherwise people can't really help